# Adding barcodes to docx

Tags: c#, merge, barcode

What is the best way to add barcodes (preferably code 39) to a docx file?
I'm printing a document programmatically and read from the template doc then do a mail merge to add the data into the template which then give me the desired document I need with a certain field containing the barcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Code 39 barcode truetype font, perhaps this one can help: https://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/. I don't have a scanner to test if this specific font is working, but if you find a proper truetype-implementation it should work in your use-case.

Comment: Great! And ignore the downvotes - your question was clear and concise to me. I guess someone was having a bad day.